# SQL - Difference of rows in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables. One with a list of users, one with items and one with relation between the users and the items. User can have an item (stat = 0/1) or can have a duplicate (dup = 0/1).

Table1

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name varchar(255),
);
```

Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item_no varchar(255),
    item_name varchar(255),
    item_group varchar(255)
);
```

Table 3

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  item_id int NOT NULL,
  stat tinyint NOT NULL,
  dup tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES table1(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES table2(id)
);
```

Sample data for Table3:

| user_id | item_id | stat | dup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 17 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 17 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 17 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 17 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 17 | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 8 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 4 | 1 | 1 |

I want to create a query with a result like this (logged userid is 17):

| UserName | My Item List | Item List |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1,2 | 3,4 |
| 8 | --- | 4 |

In My Item List should be WHERE userid=17 AND dup=1 WHILE userid!=17 AND stat=0. (means user17 has a duplicated item while the other user doesn't have the item). In Item list should be WHERE userid !=17 AND dup=1 WHILE userid=17 AND stat=0 (means the other users have a duplicated item(s) that user17 does not have).

So far this is what I got this, but still missing some items and info:

```
SELECT 
  max(t1.username) AS 'Username',
  group_concat(DISTINCT CASE WHEN t3_2.user_id = 17 THEN t2.item_no END ORDER BY t2.id ASC separator ', ') AS 'MY Item List',
  group_concat(DISTINCT CASE WHEN t3_1.user_id != 17 THEN t2.item_no END ORDER BY t2.id ASC separator ', ') AS 'Item List'
FROM 
  table3 t3_1
INNER JOIN 
  table1 t1 
    ON t3_1.user_id = t1.id
INNER JOIN 
  table2 t2 
    ON t3_1.item_id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN 
  table3 t3_2 
    ON  t3_2.item_id = t3_1.item_id 
    AND t3_2.user_id = 17 
    AND t3_2.dup = 1
WHERE 
  t3_1.dup = 1 
  AND t3_1.item_id != 17 
  AND t3_1.stat = 0
GROUP BY 
  t1.id
ORDER BY 
  COUNT(DISTINCT t2.item_no) DESC;
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: oh yeah thats table1 i will edit it

Comment: For current user = 17 and another user = 8 the rows for item_id = 2 matches *WHERE userid=17 AND dup=1 WHILE userid!=17 AND stat=0*. Why it is not listed in `My Item List` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.user_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN t1.dup=1 AND t2.stat=0 THEN item_id END) `My Item List`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN t2.dup=1 AND t1.stat=0 THEN item_id END) `Item List`
FROM table3 t1
LEFT JOIN table3 t2 USING (item_id)
WHERE t1.user_id = @current_user
  AND t2.user_id <> @current_user
GROUP BY t2.user_id
```

| user_id | My Item List | Item List |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1,2 | 3,4 |
| 8 | 2 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pPeDGMCx)

Comment: Looks good! Thank you! Just minor things: I have a lot of items and I want to order them by id from table2 but when I do `ORDER BY table2.id ASC` I get 7,14,8,17,9,10,6,11, instead of 6,7,8,9,10,11,14,17. How could I order it correctly?

Comment: @i_dont_know_anything_YET [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) supports its own inner ORDER BY clause - study and apply.

Comment: thank you! how can I show table2.item_no instead of table3.item_id?

Comment: @i_dont_know_anything_YET Join table2 to the datasource of the query simply (to proper copy of table3) and replace an operand in GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: i joined table2 succesfully, but i dont know which operand should I replace. if I switch item_id with table2.id it does not work

Comment: nwm found it. Thank you for your help. I was stuck with this for a month and u helped me BIG!